# Does Heroku support RabbitMQ currently

Tags: heroku, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

So my question is heroku support rabbitmq currently? It was addon 'rabbitmq' but currently it looks like it disabled. If heroku do not support rabbitmq, then maybe it support other broker which could work via amqp protocol?

Comment: Heroku has at least two RabbitMQ addons.

Comment: which, heroku bigwig and cloudamqp?

Comment: There used to be an add-on called "rabbitmq". It changed management, and its replacement is "rabbitmq-bigwig".

Answer (score 3):

You can [search the Heroku add-ons catalog for RabbitMQ add-ons](https://addons.heroku.com/?q=rabbitmq). There are two:

- [CloudAMQP](https://addons.heroku.com/cloudamqp)
- [RabbitMQ Bigwig](https://addons.heroku.com/rabbitmq-bigwig)

Comment: Yep, those add-ons looks great. But I'm not sure to understand... I see there are "cloud solutions", it means that a different company will store and manage that. It's not on the same server than Heroku. Isn't it ? My heroku apps run on "Europe Region" servers (it's in my config), but "RabbitMQ BigWig" runs in USA... When one of my app want to communicate with the other one it will send a message to USA and get back to Europe ? Is it faster than making a REST API between my apps ?!